# Terraform Elastic Beanstalk environment can't set up my index.php file from my s3bucket as the landing page

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

```
# Elastic Beanstalk environment
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "example" {
  name                = "aws-eb-environment"  # Name of the Elastic Beanstalk environment
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.name  # Name of the Elastic Beanstalk application
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.5.8 running PHP 8.1"  # Solution stack name
  depends_on          = [aws_iam_role.app_role]
  # Auto Scaling group settings
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = "2"  # Minimum number of instances
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = "2"  # Maximum number of instances
  }

  # Launch configuration settings
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value     = aws_iam_instance_profile.app_profile.id
  }  


  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_SECURITY_GROUP_ID"
    value     = aws_security_group.rds_sg.id
  }   

  # Environment variables for the application
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_HOST"
    value     = aws_db_instance.rds_instance.endpoint  # Database host
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PORT"
    value     = aws_db_instance.rds_instance.port  # Database port
  }
 
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_NAME"
    value     = aws_db_instance.rds_instance.db_name  # Database name
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_USER"
    value     = var.db_username  # Database username
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "DB_PASSWORD"
    value     = var.db_password  # Database password
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "EC2KeyName"
    value     = "master aws"  # Replace with your actual key pair name
  }

  setting {                                         # Allow ssh
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration" # Define namespace for environment settings
    name      = "SSHSourceRestriction"                # Define name of the environment setting
    value     = "tcp, 22, 22, 0.0.0.0/0"              # Define value of the environment setting
  }

}
```

That is the starting part of my EB environment resource, I can add more of the code.

Here is my issue which I desperately need to solve and with some assistance I might understand what I have not tried yet or if I tried it wrong and I was close.

I can't figure out how to change my terraform code in order to correctly set up my EB environment will use my index.php file from my s3bucket as the landing page.
The current provided page when trying to access my website is located in /var/app/current/ directory a default index.php what I do not understand is how I can change it when i run terraform apply(after I destroyed everything) with my index.php from the s3 bucket(the app has only an idnex.php file which connects to an RDS database.
The environment has 2 instances to which I SSHed to find the location of the default index.php.

Comment: `resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "app_version" {
  name          = "application-bundle"
  application   = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.app.name
  description   = "Application Bundle Version"
  bucket        = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key           = aws_s3_object.source_bundle.key
}`

Solved it with this